# How to import specific version of 3rd party library in Go Playground?

Tags: go, go-playground

Let's say I want to import version `v0.11.0` of [Slack Go package](https://github.com/slack-go/slack/tree/v0.11.0).

In CLI I would call: `go get github.com/slack-go/slack@v0.11.0`
but in Go Playground I can only use import.

I've tried `import "github.com/slack-go/slack@v0.11.0"` but that [didn't work](https://go.dev/play/p/Hivn8vYIVpL).

How can I import version v0.11.0 of Slack Go package in Go Playground?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The version you import is determined by `go.mod`, and `go get` modifies `go.mod`, so include the `go.mod` in the playground example.

```
package main

import "github.com/slack-go/slack"

func main() {
    _ = slack.New("YOUR_TOKEN_HERE")
}
-- go.mod --
module play.ground

require github.com/slack-go/slack v0.11.0
```

https://go.dev/play/p/cBt7MR4Kf03